# Teradata Join Syntax

Tags: join, teradata

I'm having a hard time doing what I want to do here, as SQL (and Teradata SQL on top of that) is not my main forte.

I have two queries that I want to join together.  I want **everything** that returns from this query:

```
SELECT                
  a01.fieldOne                          Q_One,  
  a01.fieldTwo                          Q_Two,  
  a02.fieldThree                        Q_Three    
FROM   
  db.table_one                          a01, 
  db.table_two                          a02  
WHERE 
  a01.fieldKey                          = a02.fieldKey;
```

This runs fine, but I need to ALSO see the results from this query at the same time:

```
SELECT                
  a03.fieldFour                         Q_Four    
FROM   
  db.table_one                          a01,
  db.table_two                          a02,
  db.table_three                        a03 
WHERE 
  a01.fieldKey                          = a02.fieldKey and
  a01.fieldKey                          = a03.fieldKey and
  a02.fieldKey                          = a03.fieldKey;
```

Right now, I have the query written like this:

```
SELECT                
  a01.fieldOne                          Q_One,
  a01.fieldTwo                          Q_Two,
  a02.fieldThree                        Q_Three,
  a03.fieldFour                         Q_Four    
FROM   
  db.table_one                          a01,
  db.table_two                          a02,
  db.table_three                        a03 
WHERE 
  a01.fieldKey                          = a02.fieldKey and
  a01.fieldKey                          = a03.fieldKey and
  a02.fieldKey                          = a03.fieldKey;
```

I understand what I'm doing wrong - I'm using an inner join, so I'm returning only results where all the `fieldKey` fields match between `a01, a02` and `a03`, severely limiting my results because `table_three` only has a handful of items in it, so most of the items that exist in `table_one` and `table_two` do not exist in `table_three`.  I want the items from `table_three` that don't match, as well as the ones that do match - I'm not sure how to do this though.  I believe it's a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - so I take everything from the "left", and join to it some things from the "right"?  I don't know, I'm guessing here...

I'm not sure how to write this code, especially in Teradata which seems to have very sparse information around the web.

## Update

The reason I asked about using `WHERE` vs using `JOIN ON` is because the actual query I have is much more complicated and I'm not sure how to use the 'JOIN ON' logic with THIS many tables:

```
SELECT                 
  a119.a                a,  
  a11.b                 b,
  a11.c                 c,
  a18.d                 d,
  a18.e                 e,
  a11.f                 f,
  a11.g                 g,     
  a11.h                 h,
  a11.i                 i,
  a11.j                 j,  
  a12.k                 k,  
  a124.l                l,
  a18.m                 m,
  a18.n                 n,  
  a18.o                 o,
  a111.p                p,
  a110.q                q,          
  SUBSTR(a50.r,8,2)     r,
  a50.s                 s,
  a127.t                t,
  a127.u                u,
  a127.v                v,
  a127.w                w
FROM   
  db.table1             a11, 
  db.table2             a12, 
  db.table3             a13,
  db.table4             a15,
  db.table5             a18,  
  db.table6             a50,
  db.table7             a51,
  db.table8             a52,
  db.table9             a53,
  db.table10            a54,
  db.table11            a110,
  db.table12            a111,      
  db.table13            a114, 
  db.table14            a115, 
  db.table15            a116, 
  db.table16            a117,  
  db.table17            a119, 
  db.table18            a120, 
  db.table19            a121, 
  db.table20            a122,
  db.table21            a123, 
  db.table22            a124,
  db.table23            a125,
  db.table24            a126  
WHERE 
  a11.someKey               = a12.someKey and
  a11.someKey               = a125.someKey and
  a11.someKey               = a15.someKey and
  a125.someKey              = a126.someKey and
  a11.someKey               = a18.someKey and  
  a11.someKey               = a13.someKey and 
  a11.someKey               = a13.someKey and 
  a18.someKey               = a50.someKey and
  a50.someKey               = a51.someKey and
  a51.someKey               = a52.someKey and
  a52.someKey               = a53.someKey and
  a53.someKey               = a54.someKey and
  a11.someKey               = a114.someKey and 
  a11.someKey               = a119.someKey and
  a12.someKey               = a110.someKey and
  a12.someKey               = a111.someKey and    
  a114.someKey              = a115.someKey and 
  a11.someKey               = a116.someKey and 
  a116.someKey              = a117.someKey and 
  a11.someKey               = a13.someKey
```

The above query (when populated with actual field names and key names) runs just fine, because the keys in question exist in ALL of the tables.

What I expect to see when joining in that LAST table (`a127`) is blank fields (or null fields) for 97% of them.  Is there no way for me to just put brackets or something around THIS query, run it, then join the results to the second query?

Answer (score 3):

Teradata uses Standard SQL join syntax like all other DBMSes.

First of all you should stop using the old syntax `FROM tabl1, table, table3`, switch to explicit `JOIN` instead.

I don't know about your data, so I'm not sure if you can simply combine both queries into one, but if it's possible it should be like this:

```
SELECT                
  a01.fieldOne                          Q_One,
  a01.fieldTwo                          Q_Two,
  a02.fieldThree                        Q_Three,
  a03.fieldFour                         Q_Four    
FROM db.table_one                       AS a01
JOIN db.table_two                       AS a02
  ON a01.fieldKey = a02.fieldKey
LEFT JOIN db.table_three                AS a03 -- your guess is correct :) 
  ON a01.fieldKey = a03.fieldKey 
 and a02.fieldKey = a03.fieldKey;
```

Check if the number of rows returned matches your 1st query.

Edit:

As you actually join a lot of tables you might try to keep the existing implicit joins and only add a LEFT join for the last table (I'm not sure if this returns the correct result):

```
db.table23            a125,
db.table24            a126 
LEFT JOIN   a127
ON ....
```

And next time start using ON-syntax from the beginning :)

Comment: Thank you for this.  What's the difference between the way I did it `Select From WHERE` and the way you do it `Select From JOIN ON`?

Comment: @BrianPowell: There's no difference, but whenever you need Outer Joins you must use `JOIN` syntax, so you better get used to it (and it prevents some supid things like forgetting a join condition)

Comment: @dnoeth Oh, I somehow skipped that part. You seem to be right then!

Comment: @dnoeth well crap.  I have to rewrite this ENTIRE thing then?

Comment: @BrianPowell is not that difficult. Start with 2 tables, then join a 3rd, etc.

Comment: @BrianPowell: You *can* mix implicit and explicit joins, but it's confusing. I still don't know (and in fact I don't *want* to know) the rules determining  what's actually returned when you mix.

Comment: @dnoeth Are you able to modify your answer to show exactly how I do join after join after join, then end it with a final `LEFT JOIN`?  And if I'm not using a `where` statement, how do I put in something like `where a01.fieldOne is not null`, or `where a02.fieldThree = 'Brian'`?

Comment: @BrianPowell: Start with the first two tables and move their join-condition from WHERE to ON (this condition can be based on the current tables and all previously JOINed) , then add the next table. This is exactly what I did with your query. Ok, after the edit it's way more complicated :)  All search-conditions on the inner-joined tables stay in WHERE (you hopefully wrote seperate blocks for join & search-conditions?). If you got a condition on the last table (a03) you must probably AND it to the join.

Comment: @dnoeth Sorry to keep bugging you, but I'm still not getting how to format this...... do you have a link that explains this to me in greater detail?  I've tried several different ways of formatting it and I keep getting errors.  You'll see that the `a11` alias is my main table, and I'm joining that to 15 or so other tables' keys.  I'm not sure how to write the join the way you've done it...

Comment: @BrianPowell: *Try to add only the LEFT join and keep the old ones*. When you start using explicit joins it's more complicated because there are scoping rules (resulting in *invalid join condition*). If you got an ER diagram of your database (or you outline your table relationships) you can follow that for the correct order of joins. There's some details (mainly on coding OUTER joins) in the DML manuals: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_151K/title.019.2.html

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for this - in the "Update" section of my post in that massive statement, where would add that `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @BrianPowell: I added that to my answer...